# Ways to design "web app" backend in C?

Tags: c, web-services, http, unix, cgi

I decided to turn a program I wrote into a "web app". It's all C. I know it can be easily set up as a CGI binary on Apache, but doing so requires spawning a new process for every single little request, which seems resource intensive and possibly slower than even PHP. Is there a scalable alternative? ASIO or something? If so, what libraries are available? Or should I just turn the program into a PHP extension?

My question is basically, can you list all the software/libraries that allow a binary to eventually interact with Javascript on a client?

Comment: You have to switch to a non-CGI interface.  CGI interface is designed to spawn a process for each request.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastCGI seems like the obvious candidate

Comment: I saw the FastCGI site but the project seemed unmaintained

Comment: what about "fcgi" then?

Comment: FastCGI isn't dead.  It's just complete.  It's a protocol—you *want* those to stop changing at some point so you can actually implement it, and there are a lot of implementations already.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI lists some of them.